# Having a hard time installing a python module (torchseq)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to install [this module.](https://github.com/tomhosking/torchseq) When I run the command

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get the following:

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/voi/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/voi/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/voi/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(self, {
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 293, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 721, in finalize_options
          ep(self)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 727, in _finalize_setup_keywords
          ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2483, in require
          items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 790, in resolve
          raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
      pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 49.2.1 (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=58.0'))
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have no earthly idea on what to do. I have tried doing this directly in terminal as well as in a virtual environment and neither has worked.